# How to find a reputable place for a meditation/health retreat?

Tags: europe, health, accommodation

I am looking for a meditation and/or health retreat in Europe, but have heard some "horror" stories from friends (horribly overpriced places, bad food, crappy teachers, etc.).I'd like to find a place far from the city, with decent facilities and good teachers, but don't know where to begin.

Would Yelp and similar be trustworthy enough to judge the quality of a retreat?
Are there forums, groups, etc where I could find accurate information on the subject?

**How to find a good place to practice meditation (or yoga, or Pilates, etc) for a couple of weeks?

And how to know if a place is actually good based on online resources?**

---

Note :
For now I'm looking for resources and advices to help judge the quality of retreats  beforehand, not for specific recommendations.

Comment: English isn't my first language, please tell me if my question is badly written or unclear.

Comment: Unfortunately, this question is a little too broad for Travel.SE. "Europe" is a pretty big place, and there is a huge variation in what can constitute a retreat center. Do you want some lonely castle in the Scottish Highlands? A Russian monastery in the far Arctic? A Yoga center in downtown Prague? A beach resort on the French Riviera? You *can* visit any of those kinds of places, they are just...very different. Are you looking for solitude? For nice weather? For interesting people to converse with? For formal classes or coursework? For world-renowned cuisine?

Comment: @RobertColumbia I'm not looking for a specific spot now, more for advices on how to judge the quality of a place.

Comment: @RobertColumbia Is asking for specific recommandations on scope for this SE ? Should I pick an area and ask something like "What are the best meditation retreat available there ?" instead of this question?

Comment: @Purple Puma You might think about contacting local yoga / Pilates studios to see if they have any recommendations, or you can research the web eg https://www.pilatesnearyou.co.uk/retreats or try TripAdvisor. You’ll need to define what you’re looking for -‘best’ is very broad. Best price? Best rating? Best classes?

Comment: Unfortunately, this site is for specific questions, ones that (generally) can be answered *authoritatively*. "What's the best?" questions are not a good match here. There are plenty of sites for asking for opinions, Yelp is a good one.

Comment: Guys, the OP just wants to know if Yelp and similar review sites can be used to get an accurate idea of the quality of a retreat. S/he isn't looking for recommendations....

Comment: It's ridiculous, laughable, and embarrassing that this excellent question was closed.